Where can we find these diamond layouts for active rosters?
I sometimes see rosters drawn on a diamond like this.

But I can't seem to find a good resource for these that shows MLB teams. Is there any out there?

They are commonly shown on in-stadium screens prior to the game, but I doubt that's what you're asking for. By the way, welcome to the site! Please read our helpful [tour] page and the code of conduct to help get started on what you can ask and other important information.

I'm mostly looking for some templates (or existing team ones) that I could use to make fantasy baseball rosters from. Just a photoshop background to drop each team's fantasy roster into the manager's favorite team would be ideal.

I found two online that might be of use to you. Unfortunately, none of them are for MLB specifically, rather they're just generic diamond layouts. I couldn't find any blank MLB templates.

Maybe this one doesn't work? Then here's another.
Okay, that is a stock photo that needs to be paid for, so maybe not the best either.
Well, I also made one (below) that might be of use. You'll have to white some out and replace it with the wanted text, and you can add a team logo too, next to the name, for example.


Hi Austin. The link to the one you made definitely won't work because it points to a file on your computer, not the internet.  You can maybe upload it here or somewhere else if you would like to make it available to others.

@AmazonDiesInDarkness I knew I was forgetting something! I'll edit it now, thanks!

You're welcome!  It looks great now!
